# Get data from other domain by get method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement religious calendar for my client's website. I have service that gets xml/json data of calendar that is on another domain. Link works, but when I try get it from jQuery get method it success but there is no data

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.get('http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=16.047624400000018&lat=45.78988090000001&yy=2014&mm=11&gmt=1&m=xml', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

For now, request is only from localhost but, I thing, it is not matter. So, is there an error or there is another way to get this data? I tried jQuery.ajax() but it is the same. The request succeeds but there is no data to alert.

Comment: it is about "same origin policy"

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers block AJAX requests to different domains due to security reasons unless "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers are set in the response from the server. When an AJAX request is coming from users, web browsers checks if the target domain is same or not. If the target domain is the same, the request is sent. Otherwise the browser sends a different request to the remote server and checks the corresponding response for the headers. If the headers contains the permission for cross domain requests, the browser sends the user's AJAX request to the remote server. Otherwise browser blocks it... The server you are sending the request seems not to be setting the headers and because of that the browsers don't allow.

As an alternative you can create a proxy at your server side. The request from the users will be sent to your server with the same domain. Then your server will send the request to the remote server (api.xhanch.com) and get the response. Then you can reply the user's response with the response you got from the remote server.

[image]

Also there are some methods to relax the same origin policy (Eg: JSONP). You may google and learn them..